# conditional based on whether or not xpath value returns

Tags: php, xpath

I want my page to display a button for "next" and "previous" paragraph, on the condition that there is a "next" or "previous" paragraph.

Here's what I have so far. I start from the paragraph id that I know and I look for the preceding and following paragraph, which I load into separate variables.

Then I check to make sure a preceding or next paragraph exists. I then tell the computer to show the link, only if the paragraph exists.

Currently everything is working except for the test for $nextPid. The test for $prevPid works fine. When I am at the first paragraph no link for for 'previous paragraph' shows up, but when I am at the last paragraph in the file a link for 'new paragraph' still shows up.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

```
$xmldoc = simplexml_load_file('/tmp/lecture.xml');
$prevPid = $xmldoc->xpath("//p[@id='$refPid']/preceding::p[1]/@id"); 
$nextPid = $xmldoc->xpath("//p[@id='$refPid']/following::p[1]/@id");

if (sizeof($nextPid) > 0)
 {
  echo "<a id=\"adjParNxt_$nextPid[0]\" class='adjPara' data-refPid=\"$refPid\" data-    adjPid=\"$nextPid[0]\" data-refFs=\"$refFs\">Next Paragraph</a> ";
 } 
if (sizeof($prevPid) > 0)
 {
  echo "<a class='adjPara' data-refPid=\"$refPid\" data-adjPid=\"$prevPid[0]\" data-    refFs=\"$refFs\">Previous Paragraph</a>";
 }
```

The data I'm working with can be found here http://jeffreycwitt.com/xml_data.xml

Comment: Post the XML, my initial guess is that there is still a `<p>` element in the document, after the target `<p>`. Do you instead want `preceding-sibling` and `following-sibling`?

Comment: link to the data can be found here

Comment: i don't see another <p> below paragraph number 33

Comment: weird, me neither. when I run the following xpath `count(//p[@id='d1l46cassir']/following::p[1]/id)` in oxygen with the id of the last paragraph I get 0 -- so i must have a problem in the php stuff i'm doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is trying to do the right thing, but bumping into a minor issue.  In old versions* of PHP, `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` would wrongly return `FALSE` in some edge cases. In more recent, fixed, versions it returns an empty array.

The PHP version that you're running the code on must be one which is returning `FALSE`.  The problem is that `sizeof(FALSE)` is `1`, meaning that your condition is always true.

#### What to do?

Well, my first piece of advice is to **upgrade PHP** to something more recent!

If you really must keep the old version of PHP, then you can change the `if` statements to be like the following, which will continue to work if/when you do upgrade.

```
if (!empty(…))
```

---

#### Notes

- The wrong behaviour exists in versions PHP 5.2.0-13 and 5.3.0-2 and 5.3.7-8.
- For why `sizeof(FALSE)` returns `1`, read the [`count() manual page`](http://php.net/count).

Comment: Wow. Minor correction `if(!empty(...))` didn't work for me, but `if ($nextPid !== false)` did. However, I don't understand why the condition for `$prevPid` does work. I'm using the `sizeof($prevPid) > 0)` and this gives me the desired effect. My localhost version of php is 5.3.1 so I guess I need to upgrade to 5.3.3. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `$prevPid` works because there are other `<p>` elements before the first one that you would ever look for. The `FALSE` occurs when the query tried to get the `@id` from an empty node set, which only occurs in your XML for the `$nextPid` when there are no more `<p>` at all in the document.